# odeint and ad hoc change of state variable

Tags: c++, odeint

I just implemented the numerical integration for a set of coupled ODEs 
from a discretized PDE using the odeint C++ library. It works nicely and 
is lightning fast, but there is one issue:

My system of ODEs has, so-called, absorbing boundary conditions: the time
derivatives of my state variable, n, which is a vector of N doubles 
(a population density) gets calculated in the system function, but before that happens
(or after the time integration) I would like to set:

```
n[N]=n[N-2];

n[N-1]=n[N-2];
```

However, of course this doesn't work because the state variable in the system 
function is declared as *const*, and it looks as if this could not be changed 
other than through meddling with the library... is there any way around this?

I should mention that setting `dndt[N]` and `dndt[N-1]` to zero might look like a 
solution, but it doesn't really help as it defies the concept of absorbing boundary
conditions (`n[N]` and `n[N-1]` would then always have the values they had at `t=0`, rather
then the value of `n[N-2]` at any point in time), and so I'd really prefer to change n.

Thanks for any help!

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Usually absorbing boundary condition manifests itself in the equations of motion. `n[N] = n[N-1] = n[N-2]`, so can insert `n[N]=n[N-2]` and `n[N-1]=n[N-2]` into the equation for `dndt[N-2]`.

For example, the discrete Laplacian `Lx[i] = x[i+1]-2 x[i] +x[i-1]` with absorbing boundaries `x[n]=x[n-1]` can be written as `Lx[n-1] = x[n-2] - x[n-1]`. The equation for `x[n]` can then be omitted.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am not sure i understand what you meant. what you wrote seems to come down to setting Lx[n]=0 and Lx[n-1]=0. which means that x[n] and x[n-1] will always have the values that had at the beginning of the calculation, which is different from what i what (and from what adsorbing boundaries are) namely that x[n]=x[n-2] and x[n-1]=x[n-2] at all times, and since x[n-2] can vary over time, so should x[n-1] and x[n] ...

Comment: If x[n-2]=x[n-1]=x[n] you have a classical constraint and this constraint reduces the degrees of freedom. Can you give me more details about you equation, then I can explain this in more detail? How does the interaction between x[n-2] and x[n-1] and x[n] looks like?

Comment: this is a system of ODEs, that result from discretizing the advection

Comment: this is a system of ODEs, that result from discretizing the advection equation: dn(x)/dt - dn(x)/dx = 0, (here d is a partial derivative and n(x) is a vector) in my case this equation describers the time development in a particle system with growth (and nucleation if the result of the eqn is non-zero), where n(x) is the number density of particles of a given size x.  since the maximum size of particles x_max is an input parameter, i need to use adsorbing boundaries so that, if any particles grows to a size larger than x_max it basically disappears...

Comment: i should add: i discretize the eqn dn(x)/dt - G dn(x)/dx ... by a simple upwind scheme, i.e., d n(N)/dt = G (n(N)-n(N-1))/Delta_x. thanks for your help!